# Rewrite request if cookie is set in nginx

Tags: cookies, nginx

I try to rewrite the link if a cookie is set, because I want to render sites if user is logged in. But I did not get catch it. I set the cookie and try to catch it with nginx to redirect. It looks like

```
if ($cookie_logged = "1") {
    rewrite / index;
    #return 404;
}
```

I added return 404 for testing, to see if it would catch or only the rewrite is wrong.

It  only get catched if I prove to unequal with != but than it catch it for all requests. I tested some combinations but did not get it work. Could anybody help me? I think it should be not so complicated but some time I run in the completle wrong direction, right now.

The cookie is stored as secure and not http_only.

Comment: 1- Are you sure that the cookie is set before the browser makes request to your nginx server? check from browser and the frontend or backend language you are making use of 2- it is sufficient to check the cookie variable (if not setting it to 0 or empty), ie., if ($cookie_logged) 3- i do not understand your intent of rewrite / index; 4- add $cookie_logged to access_log to check what value does it contain

Comment: 1: Yes cookie is set, was the first think i prove. what language do you mean?  I set the cookie from nodejs in the backend. 2: It does not enter if I only prove variable. But cookie is set in Browser. Could it be a problem with localhost? 3. I have a static start side, witch is directly send by nginx. But if user is logged in Header is changed and has to be rendered. 4 if i add $cookie_logged as seperated line nginx return error message:  unknown directive "$cookie_logged" in..

Comment: for forth point, you do not have to put $cookie_logged as separate line, instead you have to format your access log, and add $cookie_logged into that, with this we will be able to figure out what value does it logged cookie contain. to format access log for testing, just add log_format new_f "$cookie_logged-$http_cookie"; just outside server block, and in your server block, put change access_log directive to access_log filename new_f;

Comment: what do the logs show when you access your url?

Comment: i added log_format new_f "$cookie_logged-$http_cookie"; outside server block and  access_log /var/log/access.log new_f; inside server block, correct? In the log file is following line writen --connect.sid=s%3AyA7282mFMPc0o1wsb1-NEktJA8a6MDG1.STtkoYRZQGGnzEnilTd%2Bc%2FFoDYUgQaFDC4Jwfhfemd0

Comment: i think there are two dashes together, that means, $cookie_logged is an empty string or not set

Comment: can you check the expire time of the cookies

Comment: it is set to end of session.

Comment: nodejs code that set the cookie should normaly set it to 1 day

Comment: you can see that from browser? or do one thing for testing, create a dummy cookie from nginx, add_header Set-Cookie "test_cookie=12345;Path=/;Max-Age=31536000"; outside location block and then add this in access_log,

Comment: I see it in browser. So I Do some test more. I set secure to false to the logged cookie and it is access able. So how could i access secure cookies with nginx

Comment: ok i am an idiot, I am on localhost so there is no ssl connection. So it could not set a secure cookie. but why do i see it at firefox? chromuium do not show me secure cookies, becouse they are never set. Thank you very much for your help